# jQuery - mousemove does not work outside of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I have made a slider/seeker out of `mousedown` and `mousemove` for my `<audio>` element. My problem is that as soon as the user leaves the element while still holding their mouse button down, it does not register the `mousemove`. Here's my code:

```
/** Variables **/

isPlaying = false;
isBuffering = false;
isScrubbing = false;
isScrubberHolding = false;
tempProgress = 0;
time = playerE.currentTime;
dur = playerE.duration;

/** Binds and Properties **/

player.bind("timeupdate", timeUpdate);
scrubber.bind("mousemove", scrubberGrab);
scrubber.bind("mousedown", scrubberClick);

/** Progress and Buffer **/

function progressWidth(progress) {
    var calcProgress = ((progress * 100) + "%");
    $(".progress").width(calcProgress);
}


/** Time events **/

function timeUpdate(e) {

    /** Update Variables **/

    time = playerE.currentTime;
    dur = playerE.duration;

    /** Update Progress and Buffer **/

    if (isScrubbing === false) {
        var progress = time / dur;
    }
    var buffered = playerE.buffered.end(0) / dur;
    timeConvert(time);
    progressWidth(progress);
}

function setPlayerTime(timeset) {
    playerE.currentTime = timeset * dur;
}

function timeConvert(s) {
    var h = Math.floor(s / 3600);
    s -= h * 3600;
    var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
    s -= m * 60;
    var resultSubstring = ((m < 10 ? '0' + m : m) + ":" + (s < 10 ? '0' + s : s)).substring(0, 5);
    $('#playerTime').text(resultSubstring);
}

/** Scrubber **/

$(".player-small").mouseenter(function () {
    knob.stop().fadeIn(200);
});
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".player-small").mouseleave(function () {
        knob.stop().fadeOut(200);
    });
}, 3000);

function scrubberClick(e) {
    isScrubberHolding = true;
    isScrubbing = true;
    player.trigger('pause');
    var $this = $(this);
    var x = e.pageX - $this.offset().left;
    var percent = x / $this.width();
    progressWidth(percent);
    tempProgress = percent;
}

$(document).mouseup(function () {
    if (isScrubberHolding === true) {
        isScrubberHolding = false;
        isScrubbing = false;
        setPlayerTime(tempProgress)
        player.trigger('play');
    } else {
        isScrubberHolding = false;
    }
})

function scrubberGrab(e) {
    if (isScrubberHolding === true) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var x = e.pageX - $this.offset().left;
        var percent = x / $this.width();
        tempProgress = percent;
        progressWidth(percent);
        setPlayerTime(percent)
    } else {}
}
```

See it in action:

```js
var player = $('audio');
var playerE = $('audio')[0];
var playerE = $('audio').get(0);

var canvasviz = $('canvas');

var playbutton = $("#playButton");
var buffering = $("#buffering");
var scrubber = $(".scrubber-con");
var progress = $(".progress");
var buffered = $(".buffered");
var knob = $(".knob");
var analyser = $("#analyzer");
var currentAlbum = "";
var countElement = $('#playlistCount');
var titleElement = $('#trackTitle');

/** Variables **/

isPlaying = false;
isBuffering = false;
isScrubbing = false;
isScrubberHolding = false;
tempProgress = 0;
time = playerE.currentTime;
dur = playerE.duration;

/** Binds and Properties **/

player.bind("timeupdate", timeUpdate);
scrubber.bind("mousemove", scrubberGrab);
scrubber.bind("mousedown", scrubberClick);

/** Progress and Buffer **/

function progressWidth(progress) {
    var calcProgress = ((progress * 100) + "%");
    $(".progress").width(calcProgress);
}


/** Time events **/

function timeUpdate(e) {

    /** Update Variables **/

    time = playerE.currentTime;
    dur = playerE.duration;

    /** Update Progress and Buffer **/

    if (isScrubbing === false) {
        var progress = time / dur;
    }
    var buffered = playerE.buffered.end(0) / dur;
    timeConvert(time);
    progressWidth(progress);
}

function setPlayerTime(timeset) {
    playerE.currentTime = timeset * dur;
}

function timeConvert(s) {
    var h = Math.floor(s / 3600);
    s -= h * 3600;
    var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
    s -= m * 60;
    var resultSubstring = ((m < 10 ? '0' + m : m) + ":" + (s < 10 ? '0' + s : s)).substring(0, 5);
    $('#playerTime').text(resultSubstring);
}

/** Scrubber **/

$(".player-small").mouseenter(function () {
    knob.stop().fadeIn(200);
});
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".player-small").mouseleave(function () {
        knob.stop().fadeOut(200);
    });
}, 3000);

function scrubberClick(e) {
    isScrubberHolding = true;
    isScrubbing = true;
    player.trigger('pause');
    var $this = $(this);
    var x = e.pageX - $this.offset().left;
    var percent = x / $this.width();
    progressWidth(percent);
    tempProgress = percent;
}

$(document).mouseup(function () {
    if (isScrubberHolding === true) {
        isScrubberHolding = false;
        isScrubbing = false;
        setPlayerTime(tempProgress)
        player.trigger('play');
    } else {
        isScrubberHolding = false;
    }
})

function scrubberGrab(e) {
    if (isScrubberHolding === true) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var x = e.pageX - $this.offset().left;
        var percent = x / $this.width();
        tempProgress = percent;
        progressWidth(percent);
        setPlayerTime(percent)
    } else {}
}
```

```css
.player-small {
    height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ff4081;
}

.player-height-anim {}

.player-small .left {
    height: 55px;
    float: left;
    width: 56%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.player-small .right {
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    float: right;
    width: calc(44% - 2px);
    overflow: hidden;
    border-left: solid 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.transport {
    overflow: auto;
}

.play-button-con {
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#buffering {
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    animation: rotating 900ms ease infinite;
    background-image: url(img/player-buffering.svg);
    background-size: contain;
    display: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
    from {
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes rotating {
    from {
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.rotating {
    -webkit-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
    animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
}

#playButton {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(img/player-play.svg);
    background-size: contain;
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
    -webkit-image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}

.playFailed {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.next-button-con {
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    float: left;
}

#nextButton {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-image: url(img/player-next.svg);
    background-size: contain;
}

.scrubber-con {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 12px;
    height: 30px;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    overflow: visible;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.scrubber-container {
    float: left;
    height: 55px;
    width: calc(100% - 154px);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.scrubber {
    margin: auto;
    height: 5px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
    position: relative;
    top: 13px;
}

.scrubber .knob {
    float: right;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 4px;
    left: 5px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: none;
}

.scrubber .knob:hover {
    cursor: grab;
}

.scrubber .knob:active {
    cursor: grabbing;
}

.scrubber .progress {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: white;
    width: 0%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.scrubber .buffered {
    height: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 0%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    transition: ease 1000ms;
}

.time-con {
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 55px;
}

.time {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.player-small .button {
    color: white;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.player-small .button:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

.analyzer-con {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 235px;
    width: calc(100% - 650px);
    height: 60px;
}

#analyzer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    display: none;
}

audio {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="player-small">
                <div class="w-ctrl">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="left">
                            <div class="transport">
                                <div class="play-button-con">
                                    <div class="button playFailed" id="playButton" onclick="togglePlay()">
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="buffering">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="next-button-con">
                                    <div class="button" id="nextButton" onclick="next()"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="scrubber-container" nmousedown="event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false">
                                    <div class="scrubber-con" nmousedown="event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false">
                                        <div class="scrubber" draggable="false" nmousedown="event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false">
                                            <div class="progress" draggable="false" onmousedown="event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false">
                                                <div class="knob" draggable="false" onmousedown="event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="buffered"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="time-con">
                                    <div class="time" id="playerTime">0:00</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <audio id="player" src="your track here" controls="controls" preload="none"></audio>
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="count" id="playlistCount">0/0</div>
                                <div class="title" id="trackTitle">Track title</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Grab my custom seeker (left) and move your mouse off the pink area. Now do the same for the audio element (right) you need a track for it to play in order to be able to move its seeker. See how you can drag it even if your mouse is not inside it?

So how can I get this behaviour for my custom seeker?

Comment: did you already googled this? https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20capture%20mouse

Comment: If you want it to be on mousedown everywhere in the document not just on mousedown of a specific element it might have to be $(document)... which is given the mousedown function, (or whatever parent element)

Comment: @ZigMandel I googled it and it did not return any of the results I wanted. Then I went on here to ask.

Comment: @Zargold I tried that, it just says it can't get the pageX of document.

Comment: Seems like the first result is the link you want in the google search i posted above

Comment: So just to be clear you would want it so that someone can click anywhere in the world and the song will play? because that's a little strange what if you have other buttons and stuff later on when you're making the app?
How about adding a new div which the thing sits in and everything inside that div (which can have a fixed height/width) can have the event listener)

Comment: @Zargold I want them to be able to drag the seeker even if their mouse leaves the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are binding the `mousemove` to scrubber, `scrubberGrab()` will only run when the mouse is over the `scrubber` element.

Change

```
scrubber.bind("mousemove", scrubberGrab);
```

To

```
$(document).bind("mousemove", scrubberGrab);

function scrubberGrab(e) {
    if (isScrubberHolding === true) {
        var x = e.pageX - scrubber.offset().left;
        var percent = Math.min(Math.max(x / scrubber.width(), 0), 1.0);
        tempProgress = percent;
        progressWidth(percent);
        setPlayerTime(percent);
    } else {}
}
```

Comment: The error is with setPlayerTime(), I have to go for a moment. I'll take a look. This does limit the bar between 0 and 1.0. http://jsfiddle.net/m4rntywx/

Comment: I didn't see your other code, my browser bugged. 

This worked, here's another issue though: When I drag my mouse off the element, it starts marking and selecting things inside the document, can I prevent this somehow?

Comment: When your begin the "scrubberGrab" i.e. when `isScrubberHolding` is set, apply a `user-select: none` to the body and remove it when you're done dragging? `$('body').css({'-webkit-user-select' : 'none', '-moz-user-select' : 'none', '-ms-user-select' : 'none', 'user-select' : 'none'});`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select the multiple prefixes are for cross browser compatibility. If user-select doesn't work, one of the others should. Browsers ignore invalid CSS.

Comment: It's not working, they're valid properties. But they don't work when I add them to the body element. EDIT: This does not work in chrome: http://puu.sh/j1o7O/c405243742.png